# simple_form, select group_method with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I have models: Case, Doctor and Role

Case `belongs_to :doctor`
Doctor `has_one :role`
Roles table have 2 columns: `doctor_id` and `rang`

Where I create Case, I select doctor. `<select>` with doctors goup by clinics.
code:

```
= f.input :doctor_id, label: false, collection: Clinic.order(:title),
          label_method: :doctor_option, as: :grouped_select,
          group_method: :doctors, group_label_method: :title
```

p.s. I use simple_form
What I want:
I want select doctors where rang == 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not see any model references for Clinic, so I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, but here is how I would do it, given that I understand you correctly.

In your form (I assume, that original form is for creating a Case).

```
<% simple_form_for @case do |f| %>
   <%= f.association :doctor, collection: Doctor.where(rang: 2), 
    as: :grouped_select, group_method: :clinics %>
<% end %>
```

Since I haven't seen the Clinics model, I am not sure this will work, but if all models are set up correctly, this just might do it.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not topical. Thank you for answer nonetheless.